# What exhaustively causes an assembly to depend upon another?

Tags: .net, clr

What, at IL level, causes an assembly to depend on another? I know that there is a table of assemblies depended upon in the metadata of the assembly, I am not talking about that. I even know that you can forge an assembly that will not have the right depended-upon dependencies with regards to the IL code it contains.

I would like to build an exhaustive list of premises that fill in the blanks in the following sentence:

> If *premise*, then assembly A should have a `.assembly` directive to assembly B.

For instance:

- class `CA` defined in assembly A is derived from class `CB` defined in assembly B.
- method `MA` defined in assembly A calls method `MB` from assembly B.

Just looking at the `.assembly` directives only tells me that assembly A depends on assembly B, not why it should.

I am saying "at IL level", because I am not interested in C#, VB, or C++/CLI.

In CLR terms, what is the exhaustive list of cases where an assembly A shall depend on an assembly B in order for the world to spin right?

Comment: That list of `.assembly` directives in the manifest is **exactly** what tells you about the dependencies.  Technically you could decompile the AssemblyRef table in the metadata, disassemblers never bother because it is already covered by the .assembly directives and would thus just produce the same list.  So don't bother.  You could be using Reflection as well but you'd surely would have already thought of that.

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, I know about `AssemblyRef` and `.assembly`, and that's precisely not what I am asking for. I am talking about say "code dependencies", like class `C` from assembly `AC` derives from `D` from assembly `AD` implies that `AC` should have a `.assembly`-reference to `AD`. It's a list of such premises that I am looking for. Using reflection is only the easy part :) And I would like this list of premises expressed in CLR/CLS/CLI terms, not in C# or VB terms.

Comment: Clarified the question.